# Is using ini_set in a script considered bad practice?

Tags: php

I am doing a code review and found 2 places where

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

is used in a function. Is this ok? Somehow it doesnt seem right to me. Is this considered bad practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it. Consider a scenario where `memory_limit` is globally set in PHP's ini file, and you want to override that setting only for one specific script/request to allow the operation to use more memory.

Calling `ini_set` in a PHP script will only have the effect while PHP executes that particular request.

Answer (score 1):

you could alternatively wrap this function call in another function that is called, making it so that you can change the implementation if a better way comes along in the future, or if you want to update the memory limit globally with little effort

```
function setMemory($limit = '512M') {
    ini_set('memory_limit', $limit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My opinion (You asked for opinions, I think):

[START OPINION]

It is of course NOT a bad practice to use ini_set('memory_limit', ....);

But I always place such declarations at top of my script (if it is memory hungry), NOT in a function...

If you get in the habit of changing memory requirements in functions, I expect it might get hard to figure out what is the current setting if many of those functions are called in the same script.

So, for code reviewing, if it happens once or twice, is not a very bad practice, but if you encounter it a lot, I would raise a red flag.

[END OPINION]

Answer (score 1):

It is not bad.
Bacause you may haven't access to php.ini
Or some value you need only in one script.

Answer (score 0):

Using script at the start of any think tends to be a bad practice but if you are setting properties such as memory is not as bad if you where trying to execute other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If You using scripts that need 512M and You don't have permissions to change this setting on php.ini it's ok to use ini_set

Answer (score 0):

**Note** : Same PHP script can be ran by multiple users
If you have **10 users** that are running your script, your server can run out of memory : **10 X 512M = 5120M = 5G**, so be careful !

Using ini_set() function is not considered as a bad pratice, but you must follow some rules, to keep that clean:

Centralize all of your ini_set() in a same configuration file 
**custom_ini_set.php**

```
function custom_ini_set($script_path_name_s) {
        switch ($script_path_name_s) {
            case '/dir1/sub_dir1/script1.php' : {
                ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
                break;
            }

            case '/dir1/sub_dir2/script2.php' : {
                ini_set('memory_limit',         '256M');
                ini_set('max_execution_time',   128);
                break;
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
```

And call this function in your script that needs more resource :

```
require_once   ('custom_ini_set.php');
custom_ini_set (__FILE__);
```

Better to put this in XML File instead of PHP File :)